# Angular 2 Upload A File without third party libraries

Tags: angular, file-upload, put, angular2-forms, angular2-http

I'm trying to upload a file in my ng2 application using http put, i'm using rxjs pattern and i've tried lots of solutions from different posts but none of them worked, i don't want to install additional libraries since i've heard that it isn't necessary, i've tried lots of things but current code does something like this: creates request data, appends files in `new FormData()` and sends the request using `Http.request()` function provided by angular2, i've set headers and some data, everything seems to be working fine except the files, server just could not see my files, i log the request in console before passing it to `Http.request()` and it seems to be what it should, but i can't check if the file was sent after it was passed in method.

I've been trying to do this for last 2 days but could not manage to do it so if anybody can help i would be very thankful

[I've tried this link so don't flag this as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular-2)

Comment: Please show us your code. (Server and Client)

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131790/file-upload-using-angularjs-2-and-asp-net-mvc-web-api