# observer implicitly has an any type error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to follow 
[File Upload using (AngularJS 2) and ASP.net MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131790/file-upload-using-angularjs-2-and-asp-net-mvc-web-api)

from upload.service.ts (note: //error is added next to the error line)

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
    progress$: any;
    progress: any;
    progressObserver: any;
    constructor() {
        this.progress$ = Observable.create(observer//error => {
            this.progressObserver = observer
        }).share();
    }

    private makeFileRequest(url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Observable/error {
        return Observable.create(observer//error => {
            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
                this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

                this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
            };

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
}
```

and getting an error:

> Error TS7006  Parameter 'observer' implicitly has an 'any' type

I tried to use

```
(observer:Observable <any>) =>
```

instaed of

```
(observer =>
```

and got theses errors

```
TS2339  Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
TS2339  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
TS2339  Property 'complete' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
TS7006  Parameter 'observer' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Observer needs a type argument for it's type variable `T` and it's not of type `Observable<T>` but of type `Observer<T>`

Since you're calling `next` with an argument of type `number`, it should be an `Observer<number>`:

```
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

this.progress$ = Observable.create((observer: Observer<number>) => {
   // ...
})
```

Your second Observable inside `makeFileRequest` has type `string` and would therefore need an `Observer<string>` to compile correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You get the "Parameter 'observer' implicitly has an 'any' type" error because you didn't **explicitly** give a type to your `observer` variable and your TypeScript compiler is configured to disallow this.

The first thing you can do is *explicitly* give a type to `observer`:

```ts
Observable.create((observer: any) => {
  // ....
})
```

Note that the type is still `any` but now it's explicit, not implicit. That should correct the error.

But it would be more precise to give `observer` its real type, which is `Observer`:

```ts
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
  // ....
})
```